# HexBinaryAdapter in C#?

Tags: c#, java, hex, unmarshalling, transplant

I want to use C# to implement encoding function which is written in Java, but it has some code I've never seen before.

```
HexBinaryAdapter().unmarshal("publicKey");
```

Is there any similar API or method in C# or I also need to implement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [SoapHexBinary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w53728x4%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

```
SoapHexBinary hexBinary = SoapHexBinary.Parse("publicKey");
```